# Insert data in XML tag

Tags: ruby

I want to modify this XML file to add additional inner tag. I tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transaction>
  <transaction_type>void</transaction_type>
  <transaction_id>r742srui</transaction_id>
  <reference_id></reference_id>
</transaction>

    doc = Nokogiri::XML(....file...)
    doc.children.each do |node|
      if node.name == 'payment_transaction'
        span = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new "moto", doc
        node.add_child(span)
      end
    end
```

And I get this result:

```
....
<reference_id/>
<moto/>
......
```

How I can insert true into `<moto>true</flag>`?

Comment: I've used this method recently: https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Add-and-Remove-elements-from-an-existing-document. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

When you read the docu you leanr that the node has a content method where you can add stuff.

This would be the code:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(....file...)
doc.children.each do |node|
  if node.name == 'payment_transaction'
    span = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new "moto", doc
    span.content = true
    node.add_child(span)
  end
end
```

[Here](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/modifying_an_html_xml_document.html) is the docu

Comment: Any news here? Have you still problems or is it working?